# Can't print the Array in view using ng-repeat in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have designed the dynamic table with the various type of the input field.We can add and delete the row as per the requirement.
Here is my HTML view code:

```
<body>
      <div ng-app="appTable">
         <div ng-controller="Allocation">
            <button ng-click="add()"> Add </button> 
            <button ng-click="remove()">remove</button>
            <table>
               <th>
               <td>Date</td>
               <td>Project</td>
               <td>Release</td>
               <td>Feature</td>
               <td>Module name</td>
               <td>Hours spent</td>
               <td>Comment</td>
               </th>
               <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
                  <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.isDelete"/></td>
                  <td>
                  <input type="text"
                           datepicker
                           ng-model="data.date" />                 
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="text" ng-model="data.dept"/></td>
                  <td>
                     <select ng-model="data.release" ng-options="x for x in range">
                     </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <select ng-model="data.feature" ng-options="x for x in feature">
                     </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type = "text" ng-model = "data.modulename">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <select ng-model="data.hours" ng-options="x for x in hours">
                     </select>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                     <input type = "text" ng-model = "data.comment">
                  </td>

               </tr>
            </table>
            <button ng-click="Submit()">Submit</button>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
               <p>{{data.date}}</p>
               <p>{{test}}</p>
            </tr>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

Here my angularJS script:

```
<script>
      var app = angular.module("appTable", []);

       app.controller("Allocation", function($scope) {
        $scope.hours = ["1", "2", "3"];
        $scope.range = ["1", "2", "3"];
        $scope.feature = ["UT", "FSDS", "Coding/Devlopment", "QA"];

        $scope.dataList = [{
         date: '17/07/2016',
         dept: 'OneCell',
         release: '1',
         feature: "UT",
         modulename: "Redundancy",
         hours: "1",
         comment: "Add extra information"
        }];

        $scope.add = function() {
         var data = {};
         var size = $scope.dataList.length - 1;
         data.date = $scope.dataList[size].date;
         data.dept = $scope.dataList[size].dept;
         data.release = $scope.dataList[size].release;
         data.feature = $scope.dataList[size].feature;
         data.modulename = $scope.dataList[size].modulename;
         data.hours = $scope.dataList[size].hours;
         data.comment = $scope.dataList[size].comment;
         $scope.dataList.push(data);


        };

        $scope.Submit = function() {
         $scope.test = "Submit is pressed...";

        };
        $scope.remove = function() {
         var newDataList = [];
         angular.forEach($scope.dataList, function(v) {
          if (!v.isDelete) {
           newDataList.push(v);
          }
         });
         $scope.dataList = newDataList;
        };

       });

       app.directive("datepicker", function () {

         function link(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            // CALL THE "datepicker()" METHOD USING THE "element" OBJECT.
            element.datepicker({
                onSelect: function (dt) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        // UPDATE THE VIEW VALUE WITH THE SELECTED DATE.
                        controller.$setViewValue(dt);   

                    });
                },
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"      // SET THE FORMAT.
            });
         }

         return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: link
         };
         });
   </script>
```

I have taken the dataList array(list) to store the rows the of table.Every time when row will be added or deleted then respective element in the dataList array will be added and delete.
I have put the "submit" button in my view.When this button will be pressed then all the dataList element will be printed as shown here,

```
<button ng-click="Submit()">Submit</button>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
               <p>{{data.date}}</p>
               <p>{{test}}</p>
            </tr>
```

But some how the dataList elements are not printed.However I am able to print the value of the test string.Please help.

Comment: in your example, `dataList` doesn't have a `name` property. did you mean `modulename` ?

Comment: I have changed property to date from name.That was my mistake...But still it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are using plain `<tr>` element for `ng-repeat`, this will not work, as it require proper structure of table.

E.g.:

```
<table>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
            <td>
                 <p>{{data.date}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

P.S. : Your submit button is doing nothing. Just printing one statement. Above code of `ng-repeat` will work on each add and delete statement. i.e. it will print data simultaneously.

Comment: This has worked.I have couple of questions:1.How did it print simultaneously?2.I want functionality like when submit button is pressed then only the elements of array should be printed.I am very new to aj so please forgive me if i am asking any silly questions.

Comment: that's how ng-repeat works, it keeps watch on dataList element, whenever  an element is added or deleted in that object, it updates the element in view.

Comment: for that functionality of submit button, you can achieve it in many ways, Like hide and show on submit, or can assign a separate variable on submit, and use that variable only in ng-repeat.